Pythagorean Theorem for inner product space
So I have started reading reed and simon's Functional Analysis book and I got stuck in the first theorem :)) The Theorem is. 
Theorem : Let $\left\{x_n\right\}_{n=1}^{N}$ be an orthonormal set in an inner product space $V$. Then for all $x\in V$. 
$$||x||^2=\sum_{n=1}^{N}|(x,x_n)|^2+\left|\left|x-\sum_{n=1}^{N}(x_n,x)x_n\right|\right|^2$$
And the proof goes like 
$$x=\sum_{n=1}^{N}(x_n,x)x_n+\left(x-\sum_{n=1}^{N}(x_n,x)x_n\right)$$
the he argues that $\sum_{n=1}^{N}(x_n,x)x_n$ and $\left(x-\sum_{n=1}^{N}(x_n,x)x_n\right)$ is orthogonal and can be verified using the properties of inner product. I have tried taking the inner product of them but couldn't show that they are orthogonal . And at the of the proof he wrote $$\left|\left|\sum_{n=1}^{N}(x,x_n)\right|\right|^2=\sum_{n=1}^{N}|(x,x_n)|^2$$. I am not understanding how it follows. can anyone help me please?

I got the orthogonal part. Can anyone explain how the last argument follows?

I presume you mean $\left\Vert\sum_{n=1}^{N}(x,x_n)x_n\right\rVert^2=\sum_{n=1}^{N}|(x,x_n)|^2$? If so, then by sesquilinearity $$\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N}(x,x_n)x_n, \sum_{n=1}^{N}(x,x_n)x_n\right)=\sum_{h=1}^N\sum_{k=1}^N \left((x,x_h)x_h,(x,x_k)x_k\right)$$ and since $\left((x,x_h)x_h,(x,x_k)x_k\right)=(x,x_h)\overline{(x,x_k)}(x_h,x_k)=\begin{cases} \lvert (x,x_h)\rvert^2&\text{if }k=h\ 0&\text{if }k\ne h\end{cases}$ we have $$\sum_{h=1}^N\sum_{k=1}^N \left((x,x_h)x_h,(x,x_k)x_k\right)=\sum_{j=1}^N\lvert (x,x_j)\rvert^2$$

ahh yes. Thank you very much.

Although the question has already been answered in the comments, here is an answer with everything typed up in one place.
Note that if you are using that the inner product is linear in the first entry and conjugate linear in the second entry, then it is not true in general that $\sum_{n=1}^{N}(x_{n},x)x_{n}$ and $x - \sum_{n=1}^{N}(x_{n},x)x_{n}$ are orthogonal. However, it is true that $\sum_{n=1}^{N}(x,x_{n})x_{n}$ and $x - \sum_{n=1}^{N}(x,x_{n})x_{n}$ are orthogonal. To show this, let $k\in \{1, \ldots , N\}$. Then
\begin{align*}
\left(x_{k}, x - \sum_{n=1}^{N}(x,x_{n})x_{n} \right) &= (x_{k},x) - \sum_{n=1}^{N} \overline{(x,x_{n})}(x_{k}, x_{n}) \\
&= (x_{k}, x) - \overline{(x, x_{k})} \\
&= 0.
\end{align*}
As this holds for all $k \in \{1, \ldots , N\}$, it follows that
\begin{align*}
\left( \sum_{k=1}^{N}(x,x_{k})x_{k}, x - \sum_{n=1}^{N}(x,x_{n})x_{n} \right) &= \sum_{k=1}^{N}(x,x_{k}) \left( x_{k}, x - \sum_{n=1}^{N}(x,x_{n})x_{n} \right) \\
&= 0.
\end{align*}
This shows that $\sum_{n=1}^{N}(x,x_{n})x_{n}$ and $x - \sum_{n=1}^{N}(x,x_{n})x_{n}$ are orthogonal.
To show that $\|\sum_{n=1}^{N}(x,x_{n})x_{n}\|^{2} = \sum_{n=1}^{N}|(x,x_{n})|^{2}$, let $k\in \{1, \ldots , N\}$. Then
\begin{align*}
\left( x_{k}, \sum_{n=1}^{N}(x,x_{n})x_{n} \right) &= \sum_{n=1}^{N} \overline{(x, x_{n})} (x_{k}, x_{n}) \\
&= \overline{(x, x_{k})}.
\end{align*}
As this holds for all $k\in \{1, \ldots , N\}$, it follows that
\begin{align*}
\left\| \sum_{n=1}^{N}(x,x_{n})x_{n} \right\|^{2} &= \left( \sum_{k=1}^{N}(x,x_{k})x_{k}, \sum_{n=1}^{N}(x,x_{n})x_{n} \right) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{N}(x,x_{k}) \left( x_{k}, \sum_{n=1}^{N}(x,x_{n})x_{n} \right) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{N}(x,x_{k}) \overline{(x, x_{k})} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{N}|(x,x_{k})|^{2}.
\end{align*}
This shows that $\|\sum_{n=1}^{N}(x,x_{n})x_{n}\|^{2} = \sum_{n=1}^{N}|(x,x_{n})|^{2}$.
